# husband wife roles reversed

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife

my husband can't earn. so I earn and also we live in my house which I inherited from my father. I know that a woman can't leave her husband's house without his permission. does the same thing apply when it comes to wife's house ?? Also even if he starts earning can I refuse to stay in his house if he won or buys one?

Comment: Your husband is your guardian. If he can't be in charge of his family then an option for you may be divorce. Some madhhabs may allow you to not obey him under certain circumstances, but expecting him to seek your permission is wrong: When a husband can't fulfill his duty of being in charge for his family some of the restrictions of the wife can be lifted.